# implementing Subset Sum with genetic Algorithm

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm, subset-sum, fitness

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Vector;


public class Metaheuristic {

    private static int[] DATA;  
    private static int NUM_CHROMOSOMES ;
    private static int MAX_POWER;
    private static int MAX_NUMBER;
    private static int FITNESS_THRESHOLD;
    private static float MUTATE = (float) .05;
    private Vector population;
    private boolean done = true;
    int numRuns = 0;

    public void GeneticAlgorithm (int[] data, int target, int n){

        NUM_CHROMOSOMES = n;
    MAX_POWER = data.length;
    MAX_NUMBER = (int) Math.pow(2, MAX_POWER) - 1;
    FITNESS_THRESHOLD = target;
    DATA = new int[data.length];
        DATA = data;



        Metaheuristic s = new Metaheuristic();
        s.start();
        //System.out.println("s");
        }





    public Metaheuristic(){

        generateRandomPopulation();
    }


    private void generateRandomPopulation(){
    System.out.println("***Randomly Generating population with: " + NUM_CHROMOSOMES + " Chromosome(s)***");

    population = new Vector();

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CHROMOSOMES; ++i){
            int randomValue = (int) (Math.random()*MAX_NUMBER);
            population.add(new Chromosome(randomValue, MAX_POWER));
    }

        System.out.println("First Population: " + population +"\n");
    }


    public void start(){
    Collections.sort(population);
    Chromosome fitess = (Chromosome) population.lastElement();

    done = fitess.fitness(DATA, FITNESS_THRESHOLD) >= MAX_POWER? true:false;

    if(done){
            System.out.println("DONE, solution found: " + fitess);  
    }
        else{
            numRuns++;
            System.out.println("FITESS: " + fitess + " fitness: " + fitess.fitness(DATA, FITNESS_THRESHOLD ));
            generateNewPopulation();
            start();
        }
    }

    private void generateNewPopulation(){

        System.out.println("***Generating New Population");
        Vector temp = new Vector();

        for(int i = 0; i < population.size()/2; ++i){
            Chromosome p1 = selectParent();
            Chromosome p2 = selectParent();
            temp.add(cross1(p1, p2));
            temp.add(cross2(p1, p2));
        }

        population.clear();
        population.addAll(temp);
        System.out.println("New Population: " + population + "\n");
    }

    private Chromosome selectParent(){
        int delta = population.size();
        delta = NUM_CHROMOSOMES - NUM_CHROMOSOMES/2;

        int num = (int) (Math.random()*10 + 1);
        int index;

        if(num >= 4){
            index = (int) (Math.random()*delta + NUM_CHROMOSOMES/2);
        }
        else{
            index = (int) (Math.random()*delta);    
        }

        return (Chromosome) population.get(index);
    }

    private Chromosome cross1(Chromosome parent1, Chromosome parent2){
        String bitS1 = parent1.getBitString();
        String bitS2 = parent2.getBitString();
        int length = bitS1.length();

        String newBitString = bitS1.substring(0, length/2) + bitS2.substring(length/2, length);
        Chromosome offspring = new Chromosome();
        offspring.setBitString(newBitString);

        if(shouldMutate()){
            mutate(offspring);
        }

        return offspring;
    }

    private Chromosome cross2(Chromosome parent1, Chromosome parent2){
        String bitS1 = parent1.getBitString();
        String bitS2 = parent2.getBitString();
        int length = bitS1.length();

        String newBitString = bitS2.substring(0, length/2) + bitS1.substring(length/2, length);
        Chromosome offspring = new Chromosome();
        offspring.setBitString(newBitString);

        if(shouldMutate()){
            mutate(offspring);
        }

        return offspring;
    }

    private boolean shouldMutate(){
        double num = Math.random();
        int number = (int) (num*100);
        num = (double) number/100;
        return (num <= MUTATE);
    }

    private void mutate(Chromosome offspring){
        String s = offspring.getBitString();
        int num = s.length();
        int index = (int) (Math.random()*num);
        String newBit = flip(s.substring(index, index+1));
        String newBitString = s.substring(0, index) + newBit + s.substring(index+1, s.length());
        offspring.setBitString(newBitString);
    }

    private String flip(String s){
        return s.equals("0")? "1":"0";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double average = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
            Metaheuristic s = new Metaheuristic();
            s.start();
            sum = sum + s.numRuns;
            average = (double) sum / (double)(i+1); 
            System.out.println("Number of runs: " + s.numRuns);
        }
        System.out.println("average runs: " + average);
    }
}

    import java.lang.Comparable;

public class Chromosome implements Comparable{
    protected String bitString;
    public static int[] DATA;
    public int TARGET;

    public Chromosome(){
    }


    public Chromosome(int value, int length){
    bitString = convertIntToBitString(value, length);
    }


    public void setBitString(String s){
    bitString = s;
    }


    public String getBitString(){
    return bitString;
    }


    public int compareTo(Object o) {
    Chromosome c = (Chromosome) o;
    int num = countOnes(this.bitString) - countOnes(c.getBitString()); 
    return num;
    }


    public int fitness(int[] data, int target){
    DATA = new int[data.length];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, DATA, 0, data.length);
        TARGET = target;
        return countOnes(bitString);
    }


    public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o instanceof Chromosome){
            Chromosome c = (Chromosome) o;
            return c.getBitString().equals(bitString);
        }
    return false;
    }


    public int hashCode(){
    return bitString.hashCode();
    }


    public String toString(){
    return "Chromosome: " + bitString;
    }


    public static int countOnes(String bits){
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < bits.length(); ++ i){
            String test = bits.substring(i, i+1);
            sum = sum + (DATA[i]*Integer.parseInt(test));
        }
    return sum;
    }


    public static String convertIntToBitString(int val, int length){
    int reval = val;

    StringBuffer bitString = new StringBuffer(length);
        for(int i = length-1; i >=0; --i ){
            if( reval - (Math.pow(2, i)) >= 0 ){
                bitString.append("1");
                reval = (int) (reval - Math.pow(2, i));
            }
            else{
                bitString.append("0");
            }
    }
    return bitString.toString();
    }


   /* public static void main(String[] args){
    //System.out.println(convertIntToBitString(2046, 10));
    Chromosome c = new Chromosome(1234, 10);
    System.out.println(c.fitness());
    }*/


}
```

My fitness function is `f(x ) = s · (C − P(x )) + (1 − s) · P(x )` in which `C` is my target value to reach and `P(*x ) = (Sigma) wixi`, where `wi` is the element's set and `xi` is 0 or 1 (the element is chosen or not). also `s` is 0 or 1, depends on p(x) value. please help me to write this fitness.
I have just tried it but the program run with errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your code, and obviously you didn't debug it. Here are some tips though.

First `NUM_CHROMOSOMES` is 0, because it's an uninitialized field (of the `GeneticAlgorithm` which you don't use).

Since `NUM_CHROMOSOMES` is 0, this for loop is useless:

`for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHROMOSOMES; ++i) {`

Then, this line:

`int randomValue = (int) (Math.random() * MAX_NUMBER);`

Since `MAX_NUMBER` is never manually initialized (same as `NUM_CHROMOSOMES`, its value is 0, and so is `randomValue`.

Anyway, `population` is empty and since you don't test for emptyness, this line:

`Chromosome fitess = (Chromosome) population.lastElement();`

... throws an exception, because there is no such thing as a last element in your empty `population` Vector.

As a side note, `StringBuffer`, `Vector` are obsolete classes, and you never need to import `Comparable`, since it belongs to the `java.lang` package.